# sp_executesql returns different results from view than running the query directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sp-executesql

I'm trying to debug a SSRS report which is showing some dodgy results.  I'm using sql profiler I've grabbed the exact query it's running which is executed with exec sp_executesql.

The query is returning results from a view.

If I run the query as it stands including the sp_executesql, I get one set of results.
If I grab the query nested inside and run it on it's own, I get a different set of results.

I've got no idea how this is possible. The queries are identical and I was under the impression that sp_executesql simply executes the query.

Is there something I'm missing or how can I debug this further?

exec call looks something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth FROM ViewName WHERE
  DateOfBirth >= @pStartDate AND DateOfBirth <= @pEndDate',N'@pStartDate datetime, 
  @pEndDate datetime',@pDate='2010-07-17 00:00:00:000',@pEndDate=''2010-07-17
  23:59:59:000'
```

If I run that, I get one set of results.

Then if I run:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth FROM ViewName WHERE 
     DateOfBirth >= '2010-07-17 00:00:00:000' AND
     DateOfBirth <= '2010-07-17 23:59:59:000'
```

I get a slightly different set of results.

Comment: Any possibility the view occurs twice with different owners?

Comment: No...I also dropped the view and recreated it in case of any weirdness there.

Comment: @gbn Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Show us the sp_executesql call and the view definition.

Comment: And the view definition?

Comment: I came here because I had the same problem, but then I figured out muh arguments were in the wrong order.  Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try pasting the query as is (doubling the single quotes that is) into the exec sp_executesql and verifying the results are the same as a manual run. If not, then it will be something to do with the date parameter, if the same, then its likely to be some kind of owner / security item.

Comment: Yeah it ended up being the date...coming through in the parameters was '2010-07-17 23:59:59:000', which for whatever reason gave a different set of results when ran without the exec. If I deleted the time component (in the non 'exec' query), it produced the same results. I don't know why this is though...

Comment: Its probably due to your SQL Server culture formatting the date parameter to its own date format.

Comment: So...which one would possibly getting formatted? The sp_execute call, or when I run the query as it is? I mean...how can I find out what is happening, if it's being formatted at some point?

Answer (score 1):

- You are probably connecting with a different login.

This means results will be affectefd by a filter based on SUSER_SNAME or a different schema (`dbo.View` vs `OtherSchema.View`). It maybe inside the view.

- You have NULL/empty string differences somewhere
- Different databases or server

Comment: I can't see anything like that...I'm just running both of these queries locally, definitely pointing to the same db...

Comment: What does using dbo.ViewName give you?